# ¿Cómo puedo usar insertBefore con un class?

Tags: javascript

No consigo que añada un `hr` entre el `class event_1` y `class event_2`

Este es mi código:

```js
function add_hr() {
  var new_hr = document.createElement('hr');
  var reference = document.getElementsByClassName('event_2');

  for (var ref in reference) {
    reference[ref].parentNode.insertBefore(new_hr, reference[ref]);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  add_hr();
};
```

```html
<div id="whole section">

  <div id="group_a">
    <h3 class="event_1">Heading 1</h3>
    <p> some text </p>

    <h3 class="event_2">Heading 2</h3>
    <p> more text </p>
  </div>

  <div id="group_b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cambia el getElementByID por un getElementByClassName. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName Saludos

Comment: Puedes usar `querySelector` si usas un browser mayor que IE8. O `getElementsByClassName` y tomar el primer elemento de la colección que es compatible con browsers antiguos.

Comment: @Christian eso no funciona, ya lo e intentado

Comment: ¿Tienes algo de código mostrando lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: @Kaiserdj getElements te retorna un array de elementos con esa clase, tendrias que iterar sobre ese array para sacar el elemento en cuestión.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster http://jsbin.com/tibibofita/edit?html,output

Comment: @Kaiserdj Si tienes código debes editar la pregunta y ponerlo ahí; los comentarios no tienen garantía de persistencia (esto es: podrían ser borrados en algún momento futuro) y si tu código está en los comentarios, en la pregunta, la pregunta dejará de tener sentido.

Comment: Como te han comentado debes poner el código en el cuerpo de la pregunta pero no uses un enlace externo, esto dificulta su lectura y ese enlace puede caer en un fucturo dejando la pregunta inútil. En su lugar, copialo en el editor, lo seleccionas y puslsas el botón `{}` del editor o Ctrl + k para formatearlo adecuadamente. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para complementar la respuesta de @Christian debo darte unos datos que debes tener en cuenta:

Como te había dicho en los comentarios, si tu soporte es para mínimo `Internet Explorer 8`, lo mejor es que utilices [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), ya que este funciona con selectores `CSS` y puedes seleccionar al elemento en tu página con esa clase. (Si tienes más elementos con esa clase deberías utilizar [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll))

Por otro lado, el método `getElementsByClassName` no devuelve un `Array`, en su lugar devuelve un objeto `HTMLCollection`. Este objeto es muy similar a un `Array` pero no lo es. Lo que mantiene este objeto en común con un `Array` es que tiene una propiedad `length` y se puede acceder a sus elementos usando índices, pero no cuenta con los mismos métodos que un `Array`, por lo que no podrás usar en él métodos como `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `indexOf`, etc.

Para que entiendas por qué no lo debes de tratar como un `Array` utilizaré el mismo código de @Christian:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

for (var prop in items) {

  console.log(prop);

}
```

```html
<div class="item">Uno</div>
<div class="item">Dos</div>
<div class="item">Tres</div>
<div class="item">Cuatro</div>
```

Verás que al intentar recorrerlo con un ciclo `for in` obtienes otras propiedades aparte de los índices. Por este motivo, si intentas ejecutar en cualquiera de las últimas propiedades algún método de un [nodeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) como `parentNode` o `insertBefore` te dará un error de ejecución (como ocurre en el código que has situado en tu pregunta).

La mejor manera de recorrer un `HTMLCollection` es utilizando un ciclo `for` de un índice inicial a un índice final:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
var total = items.length;

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {

  console.log( items.item(i).innerHTML );

}
```

```html
<div class="item">Uno</div>
<div class="item">Dos</div>
<div class="item">Tres</div>
<div class="item">Cuatro</div>
```

O mi preferido (si tu soporte es para `Internet Explorer 9+`), usando el `prototype.forEach` del objeto `Array`, pero enviándole como `argumento this` el objeto `HTMLCollection`:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, function (item) {

  console.log( item.innerHTML );

});
```

```html
<div class="item">Uno</div>
<div class="item">Dos</div>
<div class="item">Tres</div>
<div class="item">Cuatro</div>
```

De todas maneras, dado que en tu documento hay un solo elemento con esa clase (al menos en el código que sitúas de ejemplo), lo que podrías hacer es acceder directamente al primer elemento de la colección, ya que sabes que solo hay uno. Algo así:

```
var reference = document.getElementsByClassName("event_2");
reference.item(0).parentNode.insertBefore(new_hr, reference.item(0));
```

**Información extra:**

He visto que has preguntado si funcionaría igual con `insertAfter`. Lamentablemente no existe el método `insertAfter` en `JavaScript` como sí existe en `jQuery` (nunca me he explicado por qué). Para lograr insertar un nodo después de otro, normalmente se hace con la siguiente técnica:

> La condición solo debes realizarla si deseas soportar navegadores más antiguos. En los navegadores actuales, si el nodo tomado como referencia para `insertBefore` es `null` o `undefined`, el elemento se insertará al final de la lista.

```
//---Si hay un nodo después del nodo tomado como referencia
if (nodo.nextSibling) {

    nodo.parentNode.insertBefore(nodoAInsertar, nodo.nextSibling);

//---Si el nodo tomado como referencia es el último de la lista
} else {

    nodo.parentNode.appendChild(nodoAInsertar);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando `getElementsByClassName`, te retorna un `array` de elementos, hay que iterar sobre esos elementos y aplicar el `insertBefore`.

```
function add_hr(){
  var new_hr = document.createElement('hr');
  var reference = document.getElementsByClassName('event_2');

  for(var ref in reference)
    {

       reference[ref].parentNode.insertBefore(new_hr, reference[ref]);

    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="whole section">

<div id="group_a">
<h3 id="event_1">Heading 1</h3>    
<p> some text </p>

<h3 class="event_2">Heading 2</h3>
<p> more text </p>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿funciona igual con insterAfter?

Comment: tiene que funcionar igual sí.

Comment: Y la ultima pregunta:
http://jsbin.com/duganacusu/edit?html,output



Para agregar un div dentro del div de la class (whole section), ¿como se hace?

Comment: De la misma forma que lo hacias en el primer ejemplo, creado un elemento DIV y lo insertas en el id whole por ejemplo.