# ¿Cómo puedo revisar si hay etiquetas dentro de otra con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero chequear si hay una etiqueta `img` para indicarle al usuario que no existe archivo y que si desea crear uno.

```
<div class="imagen-cnt">
    <!-- <img src="imagen/blu.jpg" alt="No se encuentra"> -->
</div>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", chequeo, false);

    function chequeo () {

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Debes explicar mejor lo que deseas. No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta. Deseas chequear si hay alguna etiqueta `img`, pero ¿dónde? ¿en todo el documento? ¿dentro de un nodo específico?

Comment: quiro comprobar si hay etiquetas dentro de una etiqueta

Comment: para luego aplicar  una condicional que diga: si hay prenta una alerta indicando que si hay y si no hay que pregunte que si desa insertar una etiqueta con la utilidad de document.getElementCreate()

Comment: En todo caso sería `document.createElement()`

Comment: si pero antes tendria que revisar si hay etiqueta dentro de otra

Comment: Pero dónde quieres buscar esas etiquetas, en el documento entero o dentro de un nodo....

Comment: Buscarlo dentro del <div> con clase ´imagen-cnt´?

Comment: si, revisar en este caso a imagen-cnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Usa querySelector o algún otro método similar.

## Código

```js
var secciones = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var seccion of secciones){
  console.info(seccion.querySelector('img'))
}
```

```html
<div id="uno"><img/></div>
<div id="dos"></div>
```

Se asignan la colección de elementos `div` a una variable. 
Para cada `div`, se usa querySelector para seleccionar el elemento `img` y se imprime un mensaje en la consola. Si existe `img` se imprime la etiqueta, si no existe se imprime `null`.

## Explicación

En [Modelo de Objetos de Documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM), en inglés Document Model Object (DOM), a cada parte de la estructura de una página HTML se le conoce como elemento. Existen diversos métodos para seleccionar los elementos, ya sea de forma individual o por grupo a los que se llama colección.

Comment: como es que trabaja for(var seccion of secciones) ?

Comment: @Gamez, `for of` es una sentencia perteneciente al estándar `EcmaScript 2015`. Aquí puedes consultar su referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of

Comment: gracias amiigo.

Comment: @Gamez, si quieres que tu código se ejecute en `Internet Explorer` debes pasarlo primero por [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) o iterar el `HTMLCollection` de otra manera, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76884/cómo-puedo-usar-insertbefore-con-un-class/77050#77050) puedes encontrar información de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: @javi tu codigo es bueno sirve como aporte, no lo fueras eliminado

Comment: ok @ElChiiniNet gracias

Comment: @Gamez: Las arroba respuesta sólo disparan notificaciones para quienes han publicado un comentario o editado una publicación. En otras palabras, al poner aquí una arroba respuesta no le va a notificar a javi, deberías publicar la arroba respuesta en la pregunta pues ahí javi ha publicado un comentarío.